# Is it possible to wait for a file write in Java?

Tags: java, android, file, ipc, native

I'd like to use the filesystem to pass information between a java process and a native process. I would like the java process to open the file and wait until a certain word is written into the file. My specific need is for Android, but I'm guessing any answer will work of other versions of Java.

I imagine I can open the file again and again, looking for the word that the java process expects to be written into the file, and sleeping between opens. But it feels like there might be a more effective way.

I prefer to use file system because sockets (which are far more natural for Java) can be a little complicated to use from native code in my set up. I'm also okay with working out something using pipes, if it makes a difference.

One more important note: the Java process is a simple command line process, not an APK app.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Your set-up sound weired: A Java stand-alone process on an Android device. Have you installed a separated OpenJDK plus runtime JAR or are we talking about a Java program in DEX/OAT format, executed using DalvikVM? Because the API you can use is different...

Comment: Yes, I am running a JAR with dalvikvm. This is for testing purposes.

Comment: Then you should be able to use the [FileObserver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/FileObserver.html) file-system monitor.

Comment: I've found another solution that works for me, but why not write up an answer so that I can check and accept it?

Answer (score 0):

The StdIn library is one of the easiest ways to accomplish this, [here are the docs](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/javadoc/StdIn.html). You could run the program with:

```
java File < input.txt
```

And write something like:

```
String word = "x" // whatever String you're looking for

while (!StdIn.isEmpty()) {
    String test = StdIn.readString();
    if (test.equals(word)) 
        // do something 
}
```

Comment: Won't it reach the end of file and quit before the native process manages to write?